# Why does Express log the server object in the console every time?

Tags: node.js, express

Although I am still relatively new to Express.js, I think I have gotten fairly familiar with it, but there is one thing that I just can't figure out.

Why does Express log the server object (listed below) log itself in the console, even though I never specified a console.log method to list it?

I wouldn't mind it since it's a test project, but it clutters up the console and I would like to find a way to disable it. Is there a option in the express function maybe?

```
Server {
  insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    request: [Function: app] EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      setMaxListeners: [Function: setMaxListeners],
      getMaxListeners: [Function: getMaxListeners],
      emit: [Function],
      addListener: [Function: addListener],
      on: [Function: addListener],
      prependListener: [Function: prependListener],
      once: [Function: once],
      prependOnceListener: [Function: prependOnceListener],
      removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
      off: [Function: removeListener],
      removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
      listeners: [Function: listeners],
      rawListeners: [Function: rawListeners],
      listenerCount: [Function: listenerCount],
      eventNames: [Function: eventNames],
      init: [Function: init],
      defaultConfiguration: [Function: defaultConfiguration],
      lazyrouter: [Function: lazyrouter],
      handle: [Function: handle],
      use: [Function: use],
      route: [Function: route],
      engine: [Function: engine],
      param: [Function: param],
      set: [Function: set],
      path: [Function: path],
      enabled: [Function: enabled],
      disabled: [Function: disabled],
      enable: [Function: enable],
      disable: [Function: disable],
      acl: [Function],
      bind: [Function],
      checkout: [Function],
      connect: [Function],
      copy: [Function],
      delete: [Function],
      get: [Function],
      head: [Function],
      link: [Function],
      lock: [Function],
      'm-search': [Function],
      merge: [Function],
      mkactivity: [Function],
      mkcalendar: [Function],
      mkcol: [Function],
      move: [Function],
      notify: [Function],
      options: [Function],
      patch: [Function],
      post: [Function],
      pri: [Function],
      propfind: [Function],
      proppatch: [Function],
      purge: [Function],
      put: [Function],
      rebind: [Function],
      report: [Function],
      search: [Function],
      source: [Function],
      subscribe: [Function],
      trace: [Function],
      unbind: [Function],
      unlink: [Function],
      unlock: [Function],
      unsubscribe: [Function],
      all: [Function: all],
      del: [Function],
      render: [Function: render],
      listen: [Function: listen],
      request: [IncomingMessage],
      response: [ServerResponse],
      cache: {},
      engines: {},
      settings: [Object],
      locals: [Object: null prototype],
      mountpath: '/'
    },
    connection: [Function: connectionListener],
    listening: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _connections: 0,
  _handle: TCP {
    reading: false,
    onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
```

Comment: A vanilla express server does not log this by itself.  So, there's either some logging in your code somewhere, in some module you're using or you somehow have some debug flags turned on in your environment that cause it to get logged.

Comment: Are you sure you have no `console.log` statements within your code calling any object which references the Server object? Be sure to check additional extensions and modules.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I double, triple, quadruple checked and there are no `console.log` statements anywhere. If it is a relevant detail, I only use Express on a online IDE called Repl.it. @jfriend00 you mentioned debug flags, if they were on, how would I turn them off?

Comment: Express debug flags are described here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html.  The http module that Express triggers off `NODE_DEBUG=http`.  It seems likely that this excess debugging is coming from Repl.it.  I'd suggest you just try your code from the regular local command line and rule out that online environment.